# What does the tab becmi cover?

Tags: discussion, tags

What does the tab [becmi](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/becmi) cover? Is this any different from all the other D&D tags we have, can it be folded, synonymed, gotten rid of?

Comment: http://nearbygamers.com/tags/BECMI_D&D

Answer (score 3):

It's a distinct edition of early D&D. The rules are sufficiently different from BX or *Rule Cyclopedia* D&D, and the historical role it played was distinct enough, that it can't really be folded into anything else.

Comment: Someone should either tag wiki it or make it more consistent with the other D&D tags.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Tag-wikied!